# How to decode this nested dictionary .plist file with dynamic keys to swift class or struct in swift?

Tags: swift, parsing, plist

I have been searching all the internet to correctly parse the following plist in swift but I cannot manage to find the correct way to do it. Please help. I have tried with multiple structures and classes with no result, the data will not fill the structures as it should.
If I try to cast it from bundle as NSDictionary it works but if I try to iterate through all of its dictionaries from class1, class2, etc appear as one single value that I cannot iterate through or work with.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>class1</key>
    <dict>
        <key>RANDOM_NAME1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>path</key>
            <array>
                <string>test</string>
                <string>test</string>
                <string>test</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <key>RANDOM_NAME2</key>
        <dict>
            <key>path</key>
            <array>
                <string>test</string>
                <string>test</string>
                <string>test</string>
                <string>test</string>
                <string>test</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>class2</key>
    <dict>
        <key>RANDOM_NAME1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>path</key>
            <array>
                <string>test</string>
                <string>test</string>
                <string>test</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <key>RANDOM_NAME2</key>
        <dict>
            <key>path</key>
            <array>
                <string>test</string>
                <string>test</string>
                <string>test</string>
                <string>test</string>
                <string>test</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>class3</key>
    <dict>
        <key>RANDOM_NAME1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>path</key>
            <array>
                <string>test</string>
                <string>test</string>
                <string>test</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <key>RANDOM_NAME2</key>
        <dict>
            <key>path</key>
            <array>
                <string>test</string>
                <string>test</string>
                <string>test</string>
                <string>test</string>
                <string>test</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Please note that `RANDOM_NAME1`, `RANDOM_NAME2` etc are random keys that i do not know, and their number may vary.

Answer (score 0):

You can read information from plist file using this code:

```
Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: RANDOM_NAME1);
```

Otherwise you want to receive all plist file as dictionary to work with him you can use this code:

```
Bundle.main.infoDictionary
```